# view and control a windows 10 desktop with raspbian?

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb, raspbian, hdmi

I am trying to control a windows 10 laptop from a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian. I would like to do this over an HDMI and/or USB connection between the two devices. It does appear that accessing a windows 10 computer via CEC connection through the HDMI is not feasible. is anyone aware of other ways to make this work?

I'd like to be able to see the windows 10 desktop from the Raspbian GUI and interact with it with a mouse and keyboard connected to the Raspberry Pi.